# Why should I re-generate a server's SSH host keys?

Tags: cryptography, ssh, hardening

[This server hardening guide](https://www.ssh-audit.com/hardening_guides.html#ubuntu_18_04_lts) suggests re-generating the RSA and ED25519 host keys. What is the advantage of re-generating the default key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who created the original keys?

If they were created by the post-inst when you installed the openssh package (or you first booted the server), that should be fine.

On the other hand, if this is a server image which come with the host keys, other users would have the same host key (including the private part).

So, in doubt, it's better to regenerate them, particularly if you are setting up a new server.

It also protects against the scenario where someone might have been able to grab a copy of the previous host keys.

Comment: Interesting & makes sense. Do you know of an example of a modern system that would use the same host key? I'm assuming all server installs on AWS, GCP, a fresh Ubuntu Server instance, etc. would all generate the key right there during install and I can't think of a modern system that would reuse naively.

Comment: @angryserver A naive "Configure a machine → Make snapshot → Use as template" would have this problem. It's not an issue of _where_ you deploy it (AWS, GCP...) but of the image used.

Comment: @angryserver It's _supposed_ to work that way, but cloud providers have occasionally had bugs and accidentally reused keys.